# Set environment variable in one script and use this variable in another script

Tags: python

I am trying to set environment variable using python. And this variable is used in another script.
My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.environ['VAR'] = '/current_working_directory'
```

after executing above python script,i execute second script which uses the same variable 'VAR', but it is not working.
But when i do `export VAR='/current_working_directory` and run the second script, it works fine. I tried `putenv()` also.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how the second python script get's called.

If you have a shell, and the shell first runs the first python script, then the second, it won't work. The reason is that the first python script inherits the environment from the shell. But modifying `os.environ[]` or calling `putenv()` will then only modify the inherited environment --- the one from the second python script, **not** the one from the shell script.

If now the shell script runs the second python script, it will again inherit the environment from the shell ... and because the shell script is unmodified, you cannot see the modification the first python script did.

One way to achive your goal is using a helper file:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f envfile
./first_pythonscript
test -f envfile && . envfile
rm -f envfile
./second_pythonscript
```

That code is crude, it won't work if two instances of the shell script run, so don't use it as-is. But I hope you get the idea.

Even another way is to make your second_pythonscript not a program, but a Python module that the first_pythonscript can import. You can also make it a hybrid, library when imported, program when run via the `if __name__ == "__main__":` construct.

And finally you can use one of the `os` function, e.g. [os.spawnvpe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnvpe)

Answer (score 0):

This code should provide the required environment to your 2nd script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
os.environ['VAR'] = '/current_working_directory'

execfile("/path/to/your/second/script.py")
```

Comment: Which is functionally equivalent to `sh -c 'VAR=/current_working_directory exec /path/to/your/second/script.py` (provided you are on Unix, and the second script is properly chmod +x and has a correct shebang line).

Comment: Yes it does the same thing, but his statement was: "I am trying to set environment variable using python" ;)

Answer (score 0):

A child process cannot change the environment of its parent process.

The general shell programming solution to this is to make your first script print out the value you need, and assign it in the calling process.  Then you can do

```
#!/bin/sh
# Assign VAR to the output from first.py
VAR="$(first.py)"
export VAR
exec second.py
```

or even more succinctly

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR="$(first.py)" second.py
```

Obviously, if the output from `first.py` is trivial to obtain without invoking Python, that's often a better approach; but for e.g. having two scripts call different functions from a library and/or communicating with a common back end, this is a common pattern.

Using Python for the communication between two pieces of Python code is often more elegant and Pythonic, though.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from yourlib import first, second
value=first()
# maybe putenv VAR here if that's really, really necessary
second(value)
```